# Query to select the product with the highest sales

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2014

I'd like to get the Product ID, Product Name and Cash Sales for the product with the HIGHEST Cash Sales from some data.

I know how to write a query which extracts all records then arranges them in order, with the highest Cash Sales at the top (see below).

Then I can select the record with the highest sales from that query.

But is there a quicker way to write this? i.e a simple query which will only return the record with the highest sales? TIA.

```
select
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductName,
    ash.price * ash.sales as CashSales 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash 
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID 
group by 
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductName,
    ash.price * ash.sales 
order by 
    ash.price * ash.sales DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductName,
    ash.price * ash.sales as CashSales 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash 
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID 
group by 
    es.ClientProductID,
    es.ProductName,
    ash.price * ash.sales 
having
    max(ash.price * ash.sales)
```

Above query will give you result with highest sales.

Comment: Hi Vishw, thanks for the prompt response. When I ran the query above, it gave me this error message: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'." Do you know why? TIA

Comment: Okay. So issue is with that having. It requires arithmetic comparison at the end. I think your query is working fine but you are getting all records. You can use `limit` OR `top` to get only one record.

Comment: Ok - yes - adding the Top clause to the query made it work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the code which worked, FYI: select top 1 
 es.ClientProductID,
 es.ProductName,
 ash.price * ash.sales as HighestCashSales 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash 
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID 
where SegmentID = 0 
order by 
 ash.price * ash.sales DESC;

Answer (score 0):

You can use ranking and grouping on your result set to get the first rank (or any other rank) row

```
select * from (select
row_number() over (partition by es.ClientProductID,es.ProductName order by (ash.price * ash.sales) desc) as salesRank,
    es.ClientProductID a,
    es.ProductName b,
    ash.price * ash.sales as CashSales 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash 
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID ) subquery1 where salesRank=1;
```

Comment: Hi Sumukh, when I ran this query I got this error message. "
Invalid column name 'a'.
Invalid column name 'b'.
Invalid column name 'Cashsales'.
" Do you know why? TIA